# JavaSript Sum data

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm, loops

Hi guys after doing various transformations I have this array of objects:

I need a dynamic function that allows me to create the following object, where `data[i]` will be the sum of `data[i]` values ​​of the object above.

Comment: how did you get 3  and 6 ?

Comment: with the sum of all first object data in 0 POSITION IN ARRAY I HAVE 3 , and i HAVE 6 with the sum of second position

Comment: @Raphael: Why the edit to remove your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

because you use angular, you can transform your data response in a class/interface. Your entire json is a list of "Items"

```
export interface Item {
  name: string,
  data: number[]
}

// let rows: Item[] = your_json
```

then, you can create your totalItem as:

assuming all your data array have same length:

```
const rowValues = rows.map(x => x.data);

// using first row of your array, you can map results for each column of your matrix (rowValues is a matrix), 
// then, iterating each row, you add the sum of specified column index
const values = rowValues[0].map((x, i) => {
  let sum = 0;
  rowValues.forEach(r => sum += r[i]);
  return sum;
});

const totalObj = {
  name: 'Total',
  data: values
};
```

Is not the best solution, but I think is working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem within two looping structure

```js
let rowData = [
  {
    "name": "TEST1",
    "data": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST2",
    "data": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST3",
    "data": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
]


var result = Array(rowData.length ? rowData[0].data.length : 0).fill(0)
rowData.map(ele=>ele.data?.map((e,idx)=>result[idx]+=e || 0))
var output = {"name":"Total","data":result};
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, could you explain it to me if you don't mind?

Comment: Please let me know what part of this you didn't understand so I can explain it further

Comment: I would need a general summary of what you do so I understand better

Comment: In the declaration section, I'm assigning an array of the same length of `rowData` and filled it with 0 by using Array prototype functions, in the part I'm taking each object of row data one by one in a loop and calculating the summation of previous value of current index and storing into the result variable index wise so after the loop completion it provides an index-based summation. Thanks

Comment: does my answer is satisfied your question? if not, fill free to contact me